# Initialize youtube api to target ajax loaded iframe

Tags: ajax, video, youtube, youtube-api, video-player

it's my first time to work with Youtube API and after I got most things done, I'm having one last issue with it which i can't seem to solve, so I would appreciate if you could take a few minutes to help.
Here it goes in simple words:

- I have a video slider (carousel). Under the main video, are thumbnails of other related videos (this is the site: kushtube.com)
- when I click on a related video thumbnail, the main player content is loaded via AJAX

What I wanted to ultimately achieve is that when the current video ends,the next vicdo starts playing automatically.
Now after I did some work, I managed to make it work like that, BUT
it only work on page load...

If i click on one of the related video thumbnails, the content of the player loads via AJAX and I cant seem to be able to re-initialize Youtube API to target the new ajax-loaded player.

This is my current code:

```
<script>
// global variable for the player
var player;

function ytInit(){
  // create the global player from the specific iframe (#video)
  player = new YT.Player('test', {
    events: {
      // call this function when player is ready to use
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStatusChange
    }
  });
}

// this function gets called when API is ready to use
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() { 
    ytInit();
}

jQuery(document).ready( function($){
    jQuery('ul.carousel-list li').click( function(){
        ytInit();
        jQuery('ul.carousel-list li.active').removeClass('active'); 
    });
});

function onPlayerStatusChange(event) {
    /* video status
    ----------------
    -1 (unstarted)
     0 (ended)
     1 (playing)
     2 (paused)
     3 (buffering)
     5 (video cued)
    */
    console.log( event );
    if( event.data == 0 ){

        var thisLI = jQuery('ul.carousel-list li.active');              //get active slider item
        var thisLINext = jQuery('ul.carousel-list li.active').next();   //get next slider item      
        var nextVideoCode = thisLINext.attr('video_code');              //get next video code
        var nextVideoTitle = thisLINext.attr('video_title');                //get next video code
        var nextVideoUrl = thisLINext.attr('video_url');                //get next video code

            thisLINext.addClass('active');                              //activate next slider item
            thisLI.removeClass('active');                               //deactivate current cslider item

            //load next video
            player.loadVideoById(nextVideoCode);

        //update video title in header
        jQuery('.entry-header h1.entry-title a').attr('href', decodeURIComponent(nextVideoUrl)).text(decodeURIComponent(nextVideoTitle)); 

    }
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {

  // bind events
  var playButton = document.getElementById("play-button");
  playButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.playVideo();
  });

  var pauseButton = document.getElementById("pause-button");
  pauseButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
    player.pauseVideo();
  });

}

// Inject YouTube API script
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
</script>
```

Do you have any helpful suggestions? I would really appreciate.

Comment: Do you mean the thumbnails that appears under any video content such as http://kushtube.com/2014/07/01/people-who-just-had-sex-brian-and-john/

Comment: If that's the case I think you can just replace the url in the iframe with the corresponding youtube url that goes along with the thumbnail. I'm guessing you have a way to fetch the youtube urls based on the thumbnail's link so use that. So long as you have the parameter `autoplay` set to 1 I'd expect it to start playing. It might not work but it's probably worth a shot.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ytInit()` when you click the `<li>` creates a new player object. I think that's not quite what you want.

Have you tried:

```
jQuery('ul.carousel-list li').click( function(){
    // ytInit();
    // just load the video from the "video_code" attr
    player.loadVideoById(this.getAttribute('video_code'));
    jQuery('ul.carousel-list li.active').removeClass('active'); 
});
```

If that doesn't autoplay, then you may have to wait for the `YT.PlayerState.CUED` (i.e. `5`) event in your player status change event listener to start the player.

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question.
When I click the thumbnail, the video loads and plays. Now what I want is that after this video plays, the next video to load automatically.
I haven't been able to resolve this as of yet.

Comment: Are you ever seeing the `YT.PlayerState.ENDED` event (`if( event.data == 0 ){`)? Also, when you click on one of the thumbnails, is it running `ytInit()` again?

Comment: I only see player states if the user has not clicked in any of the thumbnails yet (for example only if the page is loaded and they immediately plat the main video - without clicking any of the thumbnails yet).

Comment: by the way you can see player states from the developer console if you visit kushtube.com